# Why does snprintf() take a size_t size limit, but returns an int number of chars printed?

Tags: c, printf, size-t

The venerable [`snprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function...

```
int snprintf( char *restrict buffer, size_t bufsz, const char *restrict format, ... );
```

- returns the number of characters it prints, or rather, the number it would have printed had it not been for the buffer size limit.
- takes the size of the buffer in characters/bytes.

How does it make sense for the buffer size to be `size_t`, but for the return type to be only an `int`?

If `snprintf()` is supposed to be able to print more than `INT_MAX` characters into the buffer, surely it must return an `ssize_t` or a `size_t` with `(size_t) - 1` indicating an error, right?

And if it is not supposed to be able to print more than `INT_MAX` characters, why is `bufsz` a `size_t` rather than, say, an `unsigned` or an `int`? Or - is it at least officially constrained to hold values no larger than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not sure, but I suspect `snprintf()` preceded `size_t`.  If so, it'd be safe the change the parameter type passed but not the return type. as the parameter would likely undergo a widening conversion, but if the return type were changed it'd undergo a narrowing conversion to `int` in legacy code.

Comment: `printf` is a very old function.  size_t and snprintf are much younger but snprintf has to be consistent with printf as C standard committee wants to be 40y back compatible .

Comment: `I suspect snprintf() preceded size_t`  `size_t` was in C89, `snprintf` was introduced to standard in C99 [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) and was first implemented in BSD, I guess in [1991](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/commit/a3050234fce4ac8570ee9c68f8f8bc7f0c82c28b). So, `size_t` was first ;)

Comment: Also, it always bugged me: you can't specify `size` to be greater then `INT_MAX` on [newlib](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/snprintf.c#L96) and [freebsd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=snprintf) `[EOVERFLOW] The size argument exceeds INT_MAX + 1`. Which was always odd for me - `snprintf(.., SIZE_MAX` is invalid on these. To specify maximum buffer size, you should do `snprintf(..., INT_MAX`. Which is odd, because this is the size of the buffer, not return value, return value still can fit in an `int`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'd say that only proves that `snprintf()` existed by 1990, from the copyright in the file.  Note that the source code you posted omits the return type in the function definitions, and even includes K&R-style definitions, which to me implies the code has some lengthy history.  I'd think the "This code is derived from software contributed to Berkeley by Chris Torek." comment strongly supports a long history that predates `size_t`.

Comment: @KamilCuk PostgreSQL source code's `snprintf.c` file has 1983 for its earliest copyright date:  https://doxygen.postgresql.org/snprintf_8c_source.html

Comment: @KamilCuk That only proves `snprintf()` existed **by** that date. It's doesn't say anything at all about whether or not it existed prior to that date. Here's a link describing how a bug in `rcp` dating at least as far back as 1983 made it all the way into `scp` in 2018:  https://lwn.net/Articles/776745/  The buggy code used `snprintf()`...

Comment: @KamilCuk That error for the `size > INT_MAX` seems to be specified by POSIX.1-2008 (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008). (I don't have a copy of the POSIX standard but a minor change to the wording is documented in Base Specifications, Issue 7 - Technical Corrigendum 1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does it make sense for the buffer size to be `size_t`, but for the return type to be only an int?

[The official C99 rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) does not discuss these particular considerations, but presumably it's for consistency and (separate) ideological reasons:

- all of the `printf`-family functions return an `int` with substantially the same significance.  This was defined (for the original `printf`, `fprintf`, and `sprintf`) well before `size_t` was invented.
- type `size_t` is in some sense the correct type for conveying sizes and lengths, so it was used for the second arguments to `snprintf` and `vsnprintf` when those were introduced (along with `size_t` itself) in C99.

> If `snprintf()` is supposed to be able to print more than `INT_MAX` characters into the buffer, surely it must return an `ssize_t` or a `size_t` with `(size_t) - 1` indicating an error, right?

That would be a more internally-consistent design choice, but nope.  Consistency across the function family seems to have been chosen instead.  Note that *none* of the functions in this family have documented limits on the number of characters they can output, and their general specification implies that there is no inherent limit. Thus, they all suffer from the same issue with very long outputs.

> And if it is not supposed to be able to print more than `INT_MAX` characters, why is bufsz a `size_t` rather than, say, an `unsigned` or an `int`? Or - is it at least officially constrained to hold values no larger than `INT_MAX`?

There is no documented constraint on the value of the second argument, other than the implicit one that it must be representable as a `size_t`.  Not even in the latest version of the standard.  But note that there is also nothing that says that type `int` cannot represent all the values that are representable by `size_t` (though indeed it can't in most implementations).

So yes, implementations will have trouble behaving according to the specifications when very large data are output via these functions, where "very large" is implementation-dependent.  As a practical matter, then, one should not rely on using them to emit very large outputs in a single call (unless one intends to ignore the return value).

Answer (score 3):

`printf` predates the existence of `size_t` and similar "portable" types -- when `printf` was first standardized, the result of a `sizeof` was an `int`.

This is also the reason why the argument in the `printf` argument list read for a `*` width or precision in the format is an `int` rather than a `size_t`.

`snprintf` is more recent, so the size it takes as an argument was defined to be a `size_t`, but the return value was kept as an `int` to make it the same as `printf` and `sprintf`.

Note that you can print more than `INT_MAX` characters with these functions, but if you do, the return value is unspecified.  On most platforms, an `int` and a `size_t` will both be returned in the same way (in the primary return value register), it is just that a `size_t` value may be out of range for an `int`.  So many platforms actually return a `size_t` (or `ssize_t`) from all of these routines and things being out of range will generally work out ok, even though the standard does not require it.

Comment: "This is also the reason why the argument in the printf argument list read for a * width or precision in the format is an int rather than a size_t." <- there's no reason to use size_t for widths that are at most... what, a few dozen characters? even for 64-bit types.

Comment: For `%*s` you might want a width that is much larger

Comment: *snprintf is more recent* Maybe not.  PostgreSQL's `snprintf.c` source code's earliest copyright date is 1983:  https://doxygen.postgresql.org/snprintf_8c_source.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'd expect `printf()` genesis to be early [1970s](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/8), so `snprintf()` 1983 is more recent.

Comment: *...you might want a width that is much larger*. You might want that but the C standard only guarantees the possibility of outputting 4095 characters with a single conversion. (Although some implementations might be more accommodating.) 7.21.6.1 para15

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I took the "`snprintf` is more recent" to mean "more recent than `size_t`".

Comment: `snprintf` and `size_t` were both added to the language specification in C99, so neither is older than the other in that sense.  That may also have something to do with why the second argument to `snprintf` is typed as it is.  I do, however, take Chris to have meant that `snprintf` is more recent than `printf`, not necessarily more recent than `size_t`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle OK. The curse of the implied reference strikes again.

Answer (score 3):

The discrepancy between size and return has been discussed in the standards group in the thread https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=761. Here is the conclusion posted at the end of that thread:

> Further research has shown that the behavior when the return value would overflow int was clarified by WG14 in C99 by adding it into the list of undefined behaviors in Annex J. It was updated in C11 to the following text:
>
> > "J.2 Undefined behavior
> > The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
> > [skip]
> > — The number of characters or wide characters transmitted by a formatted output function (or written to an array, or that would have been written to an array) is greater than INT_MAX (7.21.6.1, 7.29.2.1)."
>
> Please note that this description does *not* mention the size argument of snprintf or the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> If `snprintf()` is supposed to be able to print more than `INT_MAX` characters into the buffer, surely it must return an `ssize_t` or a `size_t` with `(size_t) - 1` indicating an error, right?

Not quite.

C also has an *Environmental limit* for `fprintf()` and friends.

> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095." C17dr § 7.21.6.1 15

Anything over 4095 per `%` risks portability and so `int`, even at 16-bit (`INT_MAX = 32767`), suffices for most purposes for portable code.

Note: the `ssize_t` is not part of the C spec.

Comment: I don't see how the single-conversion limit is relevant here.

Comment: @einpoklum "don't  see" or "disagree"?  If "don't  see", for conversions to not exceed the 4095, and exceed `INT_MAX`, the number of conversion sizes plus the length of the other format characters  would need to exceed at least the minimum 32,767.  This would take a _long_ format and/or many conversions.  As we are primarily concerned about return values that need to exceed `INT_MAX`, the portable cases that could do this is vanishingly small.  Thus using `size_t` as a return type does not buy us more useful range for portable code as the environmental limit is a limiting constraint.